# How do I get the CDATA from a [Smack XMPP API] MultiUserChat Message?

Tags: xmpp, smack, cdata

Smack's debugging console messages show me a full message including the message detail in the CDATA I'm looking for:

```
11:45:05 AM RECV (0): <
11:45:05 AM RECV (0): message to="me@server.com/Smack" type="groupchat" from="roomname@conf.server.com/roomname-abc"><body>ABCD issues  valid 2015-06-05T15:45:00Z</body><html xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im"><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">ABCD issues  valid 2015-06-05T15:45:00Z</body></html>
  <x xmlns="roomname-abc" issue="2015-06-05T15:45:00Z" someid="foo" id="1234.5678"><![CDATA[

+------------------------+
| THIS IS MESSAGE DETAIL |
| INSIDE    THE    CDATA |
| THAT  I   REALLY  NEED |
+------------------------+

]]></x></message>
```

But in my code, when I look at a Message, all the detail has been stripped out from inside the `<x></x>` element, including some of its attributes:

```
<message to='me@server.com/Smack' from='roomname@conf.server.com/roomname-abc' type='groupchat'><body>ABCD issues  valid 2015-06-05T15:45:00Z</body><html xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im'><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">ABCD issues  valid 2015-06-05T15:45:00Z</body></html>
  <x xmlns='roomname-abc'></x></message>
```

What happened to that detail, how did the console see it but I can't, how can I get the CDATA?

Comment: I used a kluge to get things to work.  I hope someone has a better answer.  I used `ReflectionDebuggerFactory.setDebuggerClass(Debugger.class)` where `Debugger` is my debugger that extends `AbstractDebugger` and overrides `log()` to capture the String from the `logMessage` before the CDATA is stripped out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under time pressure to get this done, I reimplemented my client using [Babbler](http://sco0ter.bitbucket.org/babbler/) instead of Smack and got what I needed done.  (The CDATA I needed was preserved in  the message extensions and I didn't have to write additional code.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement and register a provider for the extension element containing the CDATA section. Refer the Smack documentation about providers for more information.

Comment: OK, I'm trying that.  The documentation seems out of date.  That is, it doesn't seem to match the version (4.1.1) that I'm using.  So I feel a little like the blind man in the dark.

Comment: If you would mention which documentation you are referring too, then I may be able to fix it.

Comment: Does this one match 4.1.1? https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/providers.html

Comment: Not sure, had to look. Which reminds me: Looking at the source is always a good idea if the documentation is off. If you find a place where the documentation doesn't match, then please report it to the forums. Thanks.